# PhoneGap Build App Rate - Cannot get it working

Tags: javascript, cordova, cordova-plugins, phonegap-build

So I got the plugin installed OK according to the log files. But for some reason, I just cannot get it to work.
And ideas?

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"> 
function onLoad() {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    }

function onLoad() {
    var AppRate;
    AppRate.preferences.storeAppURL = {
    ios: '123456789'
    };

    AppRate.promptForRating();
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `onLoad()` function twice and you do not call it. It should be:

```
$(function () {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onLoad, false);
});

function onLoad() {
    var AppRate;
    AppRate.preferences.storeAppURL = {
        ios: '123456789'
    };

    AppRate.promptForRating();
}
```

Comment: Should it not rather be:

function onLoad() {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    }
    
function onDeviceReady() {
    var AppRate;
    AppRate.preferences.storeAppURL = {

onLoad is to quick as the device is not ready. It should only run onDeviceReady I think?

Comment: it is ok, but when you will run onLoad() function?

Comment: Or it could be that there is a bug in the plugin?

Comment: include an alert('test'); into onDeviceReady() function before var AppRate; if it appear that means the plugin is not working. If you don't see the alert message that means you don't call the function ;)

Comment: Seems like it might be the plugin. The alert works fine.